# How to uplowcase Password when login in spring security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I logged in with security password 'm123' then succeeded, but when logged in with 'M123' password failed. Is there a way to customize passwords for non-case sensitive characters in security?

Config Login form:

```
http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                // Submit URL của trang login
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")//
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
```

Comment: Show your authentication manager configuration. Do you use a `UserDetailsService` or JDBC? However, it is not a good practice to make the password case-insensitiv. It is a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default no, but you can easily add filter for modifying password:

```
.and().addFilter(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
          @Override
          protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
                String password = super.obtainPassword(request);
                return null != password ? password.toLowerCase() : null;
                }
          })
```